SwiftUI Menu text alignment on Mac
I want to the text for my SwiftUI Menu to be right-aligned. This same code works as expected on iOS, but not on macOS:
    struct TestMenuTextAlignmentView: View {
    let testArray = [TestItem(itemValue: 1), TestItem(itemValue: 2), TestItem(itemValue: 3), TestItem(itemValue: 4)]
    @State private var selectedItem: TestItem? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Name")
                Spacer()
                Menu {
                    ForEach (testArray, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Should select item = \(item)")
                        }) {
                            Text(item.itemString)
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("my test")
                }
                .menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TestItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let itemValue: Int
    
    var itemString: String {
        get {
            return "test \(itemValue)"
        }
    }
}

On macOS, it looks like this (not what I want):

On iOS, it looks like what I expect and want:

What's the way to do this so that the text is right-aligned correctly with Menu?

Menus on macOS apparently likes to stretch to fill all the available width. To stop it from doing that, use fixedSize.
Menu {
    ...
} label: {
    Text("my test")
}
.menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
.fixedSize()

Now it will be right-aligned because of the Spacer before it.
